# PHP Video only plays if on local network. (mp4, mobile, desktop)

Tags: php, video, mobile, mp4, desktop

Having problem with mp4 only playing on local network. If I try by tuning the wifi access off on my cell phone, it will not work. If I try outside on local network it will not work. The browser seems to lockup, I then get could not connect if I refresh (without trying to play video). It will eventually access the site again.

here is the code...

```
    header("Content-Type:  video/mp4");
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$thisFile;
    $fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');
    $size   = filesize($file); // File size
    $length = $size;           // Content length
    $start  = 0;               // Start byte
    $end    = $size - 1;       // End byte
    //
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        $c_start = $start;
        $c_end   = $end;
        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range == '-') {
            $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
        }else{
            $range  = explode('-', $range);
            $c_start = $range[0];
            $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;
        }
        $start  = $c_start;
        $end    = $c_end;
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
        fseek($fp, $start);
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    }
    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
    header("Content-Length: ".$length);
    $buffer = 1024 * 8;
    while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp))  $end) {
            $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
        }
        set_time_limit(0);
        echo fread($fp, $buffer);
        flush();
    }
    // readfile($file);         
    fclose($fp);
    exit();
```

Comment: How did you install the AMP stack? And on what operating system?

Comment: Do you understand that Apache is protecting your PC from unwanted external Access?

Comment: Do you understand what NAT does in your router to protect you from drive-by-hacks?

Comment: @RiggsFolly

Server is Ubuntu Linux 14.04.4, installed apache when installed the server. Everything else was installed by apt-get.....

I have the router set up for Applications & Gaming and Single Port Forwarding which I forward port 80 and 443 to it.....

I connect to the server in the browser by the URL and do not have an internal DNS server.....